# Используются (или используется) несколько средств?

Tags: орфография, глаголы, единственное-множественное-число

Как правильно: использу**ю**тся (или использу**е**тся) несколько средств?
Хочется первый вариант написать.

Answer (score 1):

Предпочтительно единственное число.

При подлежащем, выраженном количественно-именным сочетанием (семь часов, несколько человек...), сказуемое может стоять в форме единственного и в форме множественного числа.

Формой множественного числа подчеркивается активность действующих лиц: И тридцать витязей прекрасных// Чредой из вод выходят ясных (А.С. Пушкин).

Форма единственного числа сказуемого употребляется:

- при подчеркивании пассивности действующих лиц: Двадцать человек стояло в стороне;
- если существительное, входящее в состав подлежащего, обозначает неодушевленный предмет или животное: Прошло сто лет - и что ж осталось// От сильных, гордых сих мужей,// Столь полных волею страстей? (А.С. Пушкин);
- при составном числительном, оканчивающемся на один (Тридцать три богатыря - выходят, а тридцать один богатырь - выходит).
  •Сказуемое ставится в единственном числе, если в состав подлежащего входят слова много, мало, немного, только, лишь: Уже много учеников посетило эту выставку. http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=5.2